# Can "reduced" be used as an intransitive verb when used in the sentence "the failures have reduced"?

Tags: intransitive

A coworker bet me 20€ that this sentence is correct:

> The test failures **have reduced**.

However, in my opinion "reduced" is an exclusively transitive verb, which means that an accusative object is missing and only the following variations of that sentence should be correct:

- The test failures have **been** reduced.
- **I** have reduced the test failures.
- The test failures **are** reduced.
- The test failures have **decreased**.

"Have reduced" without an accusative object in my opinion is only valid in a chemistry setting, e.g. when you have a reaction where one of the reactants *has reduced*.

Am I 20€ richer or poorer?

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reduce) gives examples of _reduce_ as an intransitive verb.

Comment: You are 20€ poorer. _Vehicle crime has reduced at a steady rate of around eight per cent a year since 1995_ Crime in England and Wales 2010/11 - Findings from the British Crime Survey (UK Government document)

Comment: I wouldn't ever take such a bet, because how would you determine who's correct?  I personally don't like "test failures have reduced", but there seems to be a (recent?) tendency in English to use (all?) transitive verbs intransitively.  For example, many have noted that *release* is often used intransitively ("the movie releases on Wednesday" instead of "the movie will be released on Wednesday").  It sounds wrong to my ear, but does that make it wrong?

Comment: @Juhasz Yeah, I never take such bets, because how do you determine who wins? You say, "Someone on this forum said I was right." The other person might well reply, "No, they're wrong." The only way you could possibly win is if you agreed in advance who or what will be respected as the final authority. Like, "Okay, we'll consult this grammar site and whatever they say goes." And even at that the other person might just refuse to pay. But this is all a big tangent.

Answer (score 1):

Reduced is, usually, transitive. You can say, "The new machine reduced the number of bad parts", but you can't say, "The number of bad parts reduced." The natural response of any fluent speaker would be, "The bad parts reduced what?"

I would say that the quoted sentence is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> The test failures **have reduced**.

The intransitive form is indeed in use as explained in @Michael Harvey's comments and @Kate Bunting's dictionary link.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have_INF+reduced+_END_&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows the usages of *reduced* with the various inflected forms of **have**.  The cases shown all have their phrases ending a sentence and hence are intransitive usages.